# How can I place an Task or Calender event in Outlook

Tags: delphi, outlook, delphi-xe7

I am using Delphi XE7 with DevExpress Scheduler, and I would like to sink both DevExpress and outlook calenders.

How can I send And get events and tasks from and to Outlook 2013.

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at COM automation via `TOutlookApplication` or the Outlook Object Library (via importing the type library)? I also found [this article](http://www.scalabium.com/faq/dct0128.htm) via a Google search that has code to add an appointment.

Comment: I saw that yesterday, but saw the date and just though it's outdated and not for XE7. I'll try the code out. thanks.